# next js dynamic route redirect to home page on refresh

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a dynamic route in my project and its not ssr.
[image]

When I refresh the page, it redirects to the home page, but in the other pages
the refresh works as intended.
I have actually added `trailingSlash: true` to my next.config but it still doesn't works.

```
 const redirectToLivePage = async () => {
    const result = await dispatch(
      getMeetingAction(meetingId, { shares_count: shares }),
    );
    
    if (result.ok) {
      router.push(`/meetings/${meetingId}/shares_count=${shares}`);
    }
  };
```

here is the codes of my dynamic page.

```
const MeetingPage = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    let interval;
    if (data?.data.stream_status !== 'complete') {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        dispatch(getMeetingAction(id, { shares_count: shares }));
      }, 5000);
    }

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
    
  }, [data]);

  return (
      <>
        {data?.data?.stream_status === 'complete' ? (
          <Player src={data?.data?.stream_hls_playlist || ''} />
        ) : (
          <div
            className={s.poster}
            style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${poster})` }}
          >
            <div className="container">
              <p>{BE_PATIENT}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
        <div className={cs('container', s.message)}>
          <SendMessage id={data?.data?.id} />
        </div>
      </>
  );
};

export default MeetingPage;
```

**It happens on production, In local it works well.**

Comment: Could you please share the code in a codeSandBox ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably related to NextJS caveats, I had the same issue, you can read about it [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#caveats)

It should be fixed by:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    return {
        props: {},
    };
}
```

Also don't forget to restart the app.

Hope this help to someone else.

## UPDATE Feb 7, 2023

here is an example how it should looks like:

```
function MyComponent () {
//
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    return {
        props: {},
    };
}

export default MyComponent;
```

ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props

Comment: Can you explain it more by showing where to put this function?

Comment: Where exactly do we add this code? it is very vague.

Comment: @IsaacHatilima just added a full example

Comment: @masmerino The solution provided does works also with `next export` ?

Comment: @sgargel if I'm not wrong, in that case you should use other fetching strategy like https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props which works better when create static builds, also, `next export` will fail if u are using getServerSideProps

Comment: @masmerino I am using getStaticProps along with getStaticPath, However, I am still getting this issue on refresh. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const nextConfig = {
  compress: true,
  trailingSlash: true,
  experimental: {
    serverActions: false,
  },
  output: "export",
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,
  },
};
module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Put this in nextjsconfig trailish slash true.